# Overriding Sass mixin in view template dynamically

Tags: css, sass, haml, mixins

I've defined a Sass `mixin` and used it in a class styling. I'm using the class in template. I need to decide the color on runtime. So I'm trying to override `mixin`. But its showing in `#ff0000` the color I defined in mixin initially.

For some reason I `can't use an extra class`, What could be the best solution in this scenerio.

My stylesheet `app.scss`

```
@mixin mx-color {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.my-color {
@include mx-color;
}
```

Angular template view `app.html.haml`

```
:css
  @mixin mx-color {
  color: {{custom_color}}; // custom_color contains hex-color to replace
 }
%body
  %p.my-color
    This text must show-up in custom color but its showing the default color.
```

Comment: Please add more code to your question such as the text style you are trying to override. Is it p {} or something more?

Comment: Yes @NathanielFlick. Through this example, I want to apply text style to this paragraph tag.

Comment: Yes I know, but what other styles are at play here? Your example shows no potential conflict, so it must be some code not shown in your example. Read this for how to formulate a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No its not about any conflict overriding any properties i have checked. I simplfied the code for question to avoid lots of codes. If you have heard of this type of question please do share. I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry it's very difficult to figure it out without knowing more information. Do you have a url where this code resides?

Comment: @NathanielFlick. Please review this gist https://gist.github.com/mutafaf/3d2cb45f15c4f730145946eee8031a44

Answer (score 0):

Please check the compiled HTML/CSS output. I don’t think it is possible to just overwrite a mixin and expect the SASS blocks where the mixin was used to update automatically.